# HSQLDB & Optimistic Locking

Tags: hsqldb, optimistic-locking

In MySQL, it is possible to define a table column whose value is always updated by the database manager:

```
CREATE TABLE widgets (
    widget_id         INT NOT NULL,
    widget_version    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Above, anytime a new `[widgets`] entity gets created, the current timestamp is used for its `version` column. And, anytime a write/update occurs to that entity, the system will update `version` with (again) the current timestamp.

**Is there a way to do this in HSQLDB 2.3.x?** My Google Fu and perusing of the HSQLDB docs turned up nadda.

Comment: HSQLDB has a comprehensive, if dense, documentation that includes what may be placed into its DEFAULT phrase.  If you need a link to it, you may find it online at http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/index.html

Comment: Why the downvote without an explanation? Is this a dupe? If so, please provide a link to the question this is a dupe of! Otherwise, its an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), shows effort/research, and provides all the background info needed to answer the question!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just spoke to Mitch Connor, founder and primary maintainer of HSQLDB, on IRC, and apparently HSQLDB was never built with the intention of handling optimistic locking.

Mitch recommended I try [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) instead.

Comment: i am the maintainer of HSQLDB and have never heard of Mitch Connor! HSQLDB supports optimistic locking when you use it in the MVCC transaction mode.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB does not support an update clause in the DEFAULT expression.

HSQLDB does supports triggers for this purpose.

```
CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE UPDATE ON wiget_version
REFERENCING NEW AS newrow FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
   SET newrow.widget_version = LOCALTIMESTAMP;
END
```